# recursive swizzling causes crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, swizzling, isa-swizzling

I'm using `DAKeyboardControll` on my app .
it has a method with name : `swizzled_addSubview` and implement Like this:

```
- (void)swizzled_addSubview:(UIView *)subview
 {

if (!subview.inputAccessoryView)
{
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
    {
        UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)subview;
        if ([textField respondsToSelector:@selector(setInputAccessoryView:)])
        {
            UIView *nullView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            nullView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            textField.inputAccessoryView = nullView;
        }
    }
    else if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
        UITextView *textView = (UITextView *)subview;
        if ([textView respondsToSelector:@selector(setInputAccessoryView:)] && [textView respondsToSelector:@selector(isEditable)] && textView.isEditable)
        {
            UIView *nullView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            nullView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            textView.inputAccessoryView = nullView;
        }
    }
}
[self swizzled_addSubview:subview];  

}
```

**problem**

recently in my new version that compatible with AutoLayout , i receive some crash on this method , and reasons of them :
`-[UIView(DAKeyboardControl) swizzled_addSubview:]` ,
`EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0090dffc`

i know this problem has happened for many many call , but **why** it can't work correctly ?

this crash happened only for 8 users for 54 times  , 50 % of them has a jailbreak Device , but another person has a non- jailbreak Device !

Answer (score 0):

Method swizzling causes issues at run time. I also got same kind of exception, To get rid of this, I have used BABFrameObservingInputAccessoryView, which is working fine for me. https://github.com/brynbodayle/BABFrameObservingInputAccessoryView

Comment: did you have this issue with DAKeyboard? 
thank for you reply

Comment: Definitely better than swizzling. Swizzling doesn't belong into production code.

Comment: Yes, I had same issue earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your method isn't actually swizzled, so you get a recursive call which will obviously crash. That's the tricky thing about swizzling: It exchanges two methods, so every call to addSubview would call swizzled_addSubview and the call to swizzled_addSubview actually calls addSubview.

Comment: tnx for your reply , but why did you say  my method isn't actually swizzled ?
can you explain more about this issue ?
did you see the class of DAKeyboard ?